# When I use Lcov with --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1 an ERROR happens

Tags: linux, gcov, lcov

like this, when I use cmd like follow:

```sh
lcov -c --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1 -d . -b . -o test.info
```

it will

[image: show GCOV failed error]

*(click on image for complete path)*

> genfino: ERROR: GCOV failed for /root/.../d3a  CoreCodeunitrpcommondrvd3amakeimptgunitrpdpf.dir/root/One Track/CodeCode/unitrp/common/drv/d3a/src/d3a cam.cpp.gcdata!

My gcov version is 4.7
and my gcc version is 7.1.1

Comment: The `gcov` and `gcc` version should match otherwise the coverage data cannot be extracted cleanly. Which seems to be the case here. Can you provide your OS and development environment details to have a better educated guess?

Comment: my OS is Suse Linux version 4.9.125-linuxkit (root@659b6d51c354) (gcc version 6.4.0 (Alpine 6.4.0) )

Comment: It seems there are multiple version of the GCC compiler toolchain installed on the system. In your questions `gcc:7.1.1` with `gcov:4.7` and in your comments `gcc:6.4.0` version. Probably check where all the gcov binaries are installed on your system and find the correct one which corresponds to the one used to build the code with coverage compilation flags.

Comment: my usr/bin like this 
;
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          5 Jul  1 12:36 cc -> gcc-7 ;
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          5 Jul  1 12:36 gcc -> gcc-7;
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     755720 Apr 30 13:19 gcc-4.8;
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1014264 Jul  7  2017 gcc-7;

Comment: As a side note, your development should not be done as `root`.